# When exception raised previous success transaction is roll backed

Tags: postgresql

whenever the exception is raised after  update statement whatever is updated it's roll backed.
But even the exception raised whatever update is happened it should be committed.
Please help me.

```
create or replace function modifysal(
p_empno IN NUMBER
p_newsal IN NUMBER
) RETURNS VOID AS $body$
DECLARE
p_error_message text ;
p_context text;
p_amount numeric:=5;
v_sal numeric;
begin
update emp set sal=p_newsal
where empno=p_empno;
if p_newsal >10000 then
p_error_message:= crt_error('highersalerror',p_newsal);
 raise exception e'%',p_error_message;
    end if;
when raise_exception then
commit;
            GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS 
                p_error_message = MESSAGE_TEXT,  
                p_context = PG_EXCEPTION_CONTEXT;
                p_error_message := set_context(p_error_message, p_context);
            raise exception e'%', p_error_message;
    when others then
            GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS 
                p_error_message = MESSAGE_TEXT,  
                p_context = PG_EXCEPTION_CONTEXT;
                p_error_message := set_context(p_error_message, p_context);
            raise exception e'%', p_error_message;

  end;
$body$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

Comment: That's how a transaction is defined: either all statements succeed or none.

Comment: could you please help me how to handle this scenarion

Comment: Perhaps you can try using `SAVEPOINT`s? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-transactions.html

Answer (score 1):

That's working as designed: everything between `BEGIN` and `EXCEPTION` is rolled back if you enter the exception handler.

You'd have to add more blocks to have more control over what is rolled back:

```
BEGIN
   UPDATE ...
   BEGIN
      RAISE EXCEPTION ...
   EXCEPTION
      WHEN ...
   END;
END;
```

Use blocks with an `EXCEPTION` clause only when necessary, because each such block will start a subtransaction, which is quite expensive.